# Deploying Node.js using Azure CLI and Git

Tags: node.js, git, azure

I am trying to get my head around Node.js and using it for building bots.  There's a long convoluted reason why I need to do this, the TLDR version is I need it for university.

Anyway, I have found a book online, it's called "Building Bots with Node.js" by Packt publishing.  I am working through the book, and I have got to a section where I am supposed to Deploy my app to azure.  The book says to do the following, in order:

1. Create a site with `azure site create --git (sitename)`
2. Run `git add .`
3. Run `git commit -m "TwilioNodeBot first commit`
4. Run `git push azure master`

Now, steps 1-3 worked fine.  But when I get to step 4, I get a Windows pop-up asking me to enter credentials for my site.  I have tried everything I can think of, but no matter what I enter I get the following error:

`fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://username@sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/sitename.git/'`

Now, the thing is, it says the following in the book:

"After you type these commands, if you've never set up git/FTP deployment credentials for your Azure subscription, you'll also be prompted to create them. You can also enter these credentials on the Azure Portal."

I was never asked to create credentials.  I did a bit of web searching and found out how to go into my portal and view my publishing profile, and get the username/password out of there.  But when I do enter this information it doesn't work.  I even tried resetting my credentials, but this didn't work either.

There's no information in the book about what to do here, and I cannot contact the author as there is no contact info.

Any ideas?  What am I supposed to use for my publishing credentials?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  I had to open my "config" file in the ".git" folder and update the username at the start of the url.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so that others can benefit from it. Thanks